# Supersized jQuery plugin: preloader .gif image isn't visible in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, gif

Had anyone experienced that issue before? What would be a good solution?

I'm using Supersized jQuery plugin to load full-screen background image. Supersized uses a `.gif` image as a basic preloader. That image is displayed perfectly well in all the browsers except IE, where it's invisible.

How do I get this fixed?

---

**UPDATE**

This is what CSS looks like for that div:

```
#supersized-loader {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index:10;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    margin:-30px 0 0 -30px;
    text-indent:-999em;
    background-color:#111;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) url(../images/progress.gif) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

For some reason it renders the background color on top of the image. When I remove these: `background-color:#111; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8)` I can see the image. How can I modify it to make it work in IE?

Would appreciate your advice!

Comment: is it possible that the loading gif is behind other elements on the page?

Comment: It has z-index of 10, whereas the background image has z-index of minus 999; so it can't be behind anything, can it? But even when I set z-index for the .gif image to 999, it remains invisible in IE7. There has to be something else.

Comment: would you be able to give us the code of you websites (a live example would be the best).

Comment: Yes, I would be grateful if you could take a look. I added the link to the body of my post. The .gif is perfectly visible everywhere except IE.

Comment: in IE I notice a dark grey square without the loading gif, is that what you're getting aswel?

Comment: Exactly. A dark grey square in IE; a dark grey square with rounded corners and rotating .gif image on top in all the other browsers. I don't care much about rounded corners, but I do want that damn .gif to show up. I would value your ideas.

Comment: My first guess would still be that this grey box is placed on top of the image by mistake (perhaps by the z-index which you've mentioned). If the image was not working IE would definitly show us a red X.. Do you have access to the JS code that loads in the image? It's worth trying to load the loader GIF as a background and see if the image in IE works at all.

Comment: That's an idea... Let me try something real quick.

Comment: Ok, post back here if you got anything to evaluate :)

Comment: OK, found the culprit, thanks to your help. When I remove the background, I can see the .gif. So for some reason IE renders the CSS background color on top of the .gif image, even though they are in the same div. Any suggestions on how to fix that? (Please see the code and the details in the body of my post.)

Comment: I'd suggest just to add a div inside the colored background div with the image loader. Then hiding the 'loading box' would hide the background aswell as the content inside (the GIF). I think that solves you're problem. To be sure, just make sure the div of the GIF has a higher z-index.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. The #supersized-loader div is prepended dynamically with jQuery, and I may be mistaken but it looks like jQuery doesn't have the option of prepending nested div's. I placed a div inside the div and prepended them both with jQuery, but the inner div is being ignored. Would be grateful for more ideas!

Comment: sounds strange that if it does the loader itself that it's hiding behind a background. What happens if you change the CSS for background: to just background-url (without the rgb color).

Comment: Nothing changes. I tried that.

Comment: OK. Found a duct tape solution, only thanks to your support. "No background, a better gif" is the answer. Much appreciate the time you dedicated to helping me.

Comment: sorry i couldnt completely help.

Comment: You did though. I wouldn't have found any solution without you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is the result of my discussion with PENDO (see comments). Apparently, IE7 renders the animated .gif image below the background color in the same div. Also jQuery doesn't seem to allow to prepend nested divs, and as a result I couldn't place the loader gif image inside the background div in supersized plugin. The workable solution was to remove the background completely in CSS and replace the relatively ugly default .gif of supersized plugin with a nicer-looking one that doesn't need any background.

Comment: A correction: I looked into it, and nested div can indeed be prepended with jQuery. However, unless I'm very much mistaken, it appears that EI7 still doesn't render the gif image when it's prepended inside another div with the solid color background. So the solution I came up with is the only working solution for me, so far.

Comment: You could, just to try, create an HTML template containing just the background (fullsize), loadingbox (background) and loading GIF inside. To see if it works then, if that does, than jQuery/Supersize is messing things up, if that still doesn't work, there's a CSS bug that needs to be fixed ;-)

Comment: I guess I should do it just for purely scientific reasons... but I probably won't find time. Already busy with a bunch of other (more challenging) jQ issues to resolve.

Comment: hehe, then we'll leave it for now hehe! Perhaps I can be helpfull with any other jQ issues you have.